# Opencart-2.1.0.2 custom field sort order issue with registration page

Tags: opencart2.x

I have installed open cart **version 2.1.0.2**.

I have added one custom field  named **phone number** from administrator section and assigned the `sort-order 6` to this field.

When I check the registration page  I am unable to see this field, but when I change the `sort order to 5 or 7` then this field is visible . I am not sure why for sort order 6, this field does not show on registration page.

Answer (score 0):

In registration field, there is one condition missing in javascript for  `sort order in custom filed`

**Condition** : When `data-sort` is equal to `form-group lenght`

Update you code with following in your `register.tpl` file. line no arround 533.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
// Sort the custom fields
    $('#account .form-group[data-sort]').detach().each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('data-sort') >= 0 && $(this).attr('data-sort') <= $('#account .form-group').length) {
            $('#account .form-group').eq($(this).attr('data-sort')).before(this);
        }

        if ($(this).attr('data-sort') > $('#account .form-group').length) {
            $('#account .form-group:last').after(this);
        }

        if ($(this).attr('data-sort') == $('#account .form-group').length) {
            $('#account .form-group:last').after(this);
        }

        if ($(this).attr('data-sort') < -$('#account .form-group').length) {
            $('#account .form-group:first').before(this);
        }
    });

    $('#address .form-group[data-sort]').detach().each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('data-sort') >= 0 && $(this).attr('data-sort') <= $('#address .form-group').length) {
            $('#address .form-group').eq($(this).attr('data-sort')).before(this);
        }

        if ($(this).attr('data-sort') > $('#address .form-group').length) {
            $('#address .form-group:last').after(this);
        }

        if ($(this).attr('data-sort') == $('#address .form-group').length) {
            $('#address .form-group:last').after(this);
        }

        if ($(this).attr('data-sort') < -$('#address .form-group').length) {
            $('#address .form-group:first').before(this);
        }
    });
</script>
```